# What is a Functional Descriptor in USB standards?

Tags: usb, libusb, dfu

I am new to USB and I am trying to develop a library that can do `Device Firmware Upgrade` in our application.

The DFU Standard http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/DFU_1.1.pdf talks about `Run-Time DFU Functional Descriptor`. 
I understand what `Device`, `configuration`, `interface` and `endpoint` descriptors are but I don't know what `Functional` descriptors are. Therefore my questions are:

`1`. What is a Functional Descriptor?

`2`. How do I retrieve information about Functional Descriptor?

I am working with `libusb`to do my work. So if you have any examples, that'll be great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1 -** Device, Configuration, Interface, Endpoint are standard descriptors for defining a device and its interfaces. These descriptors contain generic information and can be read by the USB device driver.

> But Functional descriptors are device class specific and its known to
>   only the class drivers. So every class such as CDC, DFU, HID, etc. has
>   their own functional descriptor specific to the class functionalities.

Functional descriptor describes the class specific contents within interface descriptor. A class specific interface descriptor can have more than one functional descriptor. Functional descriptors have common header format.

**2 -** Since functional descriptors are part of class interface descriptor, please read the interface descriptor using libusb API and you will get the functional descriptor too.